# How do I create a Paperclip attachment (from raw bytes? (maybe)) without having the file stored on disk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

This works (but seems tedious):

```
  File.new("temp.pdf", "w").close
  File.open("temp.pdf", "w+") do |f|
    f.write(response.body)
    pdf = PDF.new({
      :document    => f,
    })
    pdf.save

  end

  # delete the temp file
  File.delete("temp.pdf")
```

But, I would rather not have to do the create, write, upload delete stuff every time I want to create a PDF on the S3 Bucket

This is what I would like to do:

```
        pdf = PDF.new({
            :document    => response.body,
        })
        pdf.save
```

But, seeing as response.body is just a bunch of bytes (I think, I'm not sure about the format of response.body or how to look it up), paperclip doesn't know to convert that to a file.

Note: response.body is from DocRaptor: http://docraptor.com/ which converts html to PDF.

Comment: i am currently looking into this very issue, using docraptor with paperclip as well.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: I think so, but I left the company that I was doing this for, so... :-\ sorry, I don't have access to the code anymore